# Can't use a fragment in more than one other fragment...?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-js

I suppose it's because it's relatively new, but it's been such a pain working out what's a bug and what's actually an error in Apollo.

I've created a fragment called 'EventFragment', which I'd like to spread into 2 other fragments.

It works fine provided it's only in one, but as soon as it's in more than one, I get the error "There can be only one fragment named EventFragment" which, obviously there isn't.

Is this a bug, or can I actually only use a fragment in one other context?

```
    import gql from 'graphql-tag'

    export const EventFragment = gql`
        fragment EventFragment on Event {
            id
            createdAt
            updatedAt
            deletedAt
            title
            description
            type
            date
            isSystem
            addedBy {
                id
                firstName
                lastName
            }
            liability {
                id
                loan {
                    id
                    name
                }
            }
            isRepeating
            repeatNumber
            repeatUnit
            files {
                id
                createdAt
                updatedAt
                deletedAt
                filename
            }
            company {
                id
            }
            person {
                id
            }
        }
    `

    export const LiabilityFragment = gql`
        fragment LiabilityFragment on Liability {
            id
            createdAt
            updatedAt
            deletedAt
            name
            isFixed
            loanTerm
            interestOnlyTerm
            startDate
            financePurpose
            limit
            amount
            initialBalance
            repaymentAmount
            repaymentFrequency
            discountPercent
            bankAccountName
            bankAccountBsb
            bankAccountNumber
            assets {
                id
                deletedAt
                name
                address {
                    id
                    address
                }
            }
            people {
                id
                percent
                person {
                    id
                    firstName
                    lastName
                    deletedAt
                }
            }
            companies {
                id
                percent
                company {
                    id
                    name
                    deletedAt
                }
            }
            loan {
                id
                name
            }
            events {
                ...EventFragment
            }
        }
        ${EventFragment}
    `

    export const PersonFragment = gql`
        fragment PersonFragment on Person {
            id
            createdAt
            updatedAt
            title
            firstName
            middleName
            lastName
            preferredName
            previousName
            address {
                id
                offPlan
                level
                building
                unitNumber
                address
            }
            dateOfBirth
            gender
            maritalStatus
            email
            phonePreference
            phoneHome
            phoneWork
            phoneMobile
            phoneFax
            actingOnTrust
            trustName
            dependants {
                id
                name
                age
            }
            liabilities {
                id
                percent
                deletedAt
                personRelation {
                    ...LiabilityFragment
                }
                companyRelation {
                    ...LiabilityFragment
                }
            }
            assets {
                id
                percent
                deletedAt
                personRelation {
                    ...AssetFragment
                }
                companyRelation {
                    ...AssetFragment
                } 
            }
            events {
                ...EventFragment
            }
        }
        ${LiabilityFragment}
        ${AssetFragment}
        ${EventFragment}
    `
```

Comment: IMHO all `${.....}` causes redefinitions.

Comment: Ah. Is there a way around using this, in that case?

Comment: One way around this is to utilize the pre-compiled graphql files with webpack if you have access, those files have direct import capability and dont need to be compiled at run-time. I am working on a solution to this and I believe it is just a naming issue, because this is currently how I am structuring my project.